# How to append a component on button click

Tags: vue.js

I have a component  that I have loading in app.vue. I have a button that I'm using to call a method to try and add another instance of that component so I can have however many instances of that component on the page

When I call div.append(EquipmentInput);, it just appends [object Object] to the DOM.

html:

```
            <div id="eDiv">
            <EquipmentInput></EquipmentInput>
                <button class="block mx-auto px-4 py-2 rounded-full bg-gray-200 hover:bg-blue-300 hover:font-bold" v-on:click.prevent="addEquipmentLine">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="text
```

method:

```
addEquipmentLine(){
            let eDiv = document.getElementById('eDiv');
            eDiv.append(EquipmentInput);
            },
```

I think it should be appending another instance of the component, but it's just appending that object text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you do something like this: [Inserting in DOM](https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/#article-header-id-1).

1. Use a `$ref` instead of an ID
2. Create a new element and `$mount` it
3. Get the `$ref` of the parent and append the DOM element that way

```js
const EquipmentInput = Vue.extend({
  template: "<div>Hello World</div>"
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    EquipmentInput
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      const instance = new EquipmentInput();
      instance.$mount();
      this.$refs.ediv.appendChild(instance.$el);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div ref="ediv"></div>
  <button @click="add">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! took a little refactoring from the link you provided, but that worked like a charm!